# Rectangle image scale to aspect fit square to use with MPMediaItemArtwork

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

```
MPMediaItemArtwork *albumArt = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage:image]];
```

I have an `UIImage` which is `rectangle`, It's cropped to square when I put it to `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` using `MPMediaItemArtwork`. How can I resize an `UIImage` to fit a `square UIImage` by width and leave the rest in blank?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put `UIImage` into an `UIImageView`, set `contentMode` for `UIImageView` is `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` and render it back to `UIImage`.

```
+ (UIImage *)imageToSquare:(UIImage *)image byWidth:(float)width{
        UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, width)];
        [view setImage:image];
        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
        [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

        UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return img;
    }
```

Comment: Awesome answer!

Comment: But when running on Xcode it is giving a warning " [UIImageView initWithFrame:] must be used from main thread"

Comment: Please refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081731/uiapplication-delegate-must-be-called-from-main-thread-only

Answer (score 0):

Here's Jared answer in Swift:

```
func imageToSquare(_ image: UIImage, with dimension: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let size = CGSize(width: dimension, height: dimension)
        let iv = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
        
       return renderer.image { ctx in
            iv.layer.render(in: ctx.cgContext)
        }
    }
```