# -[UIApplication delegate] must be called from main thread only

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa-touch, thread-safety, uiapplication

This warning leads to a serious problem cause I really can't call the delegate outside of the main thread using Xcode 9 beta 2. Strange thing is that this was working when I was using Xcode 8.3.3.

Also I thought it would only be good practice to call delegates from main thread only, isn't it? So why is this causing the app to crash now?

Comment: Apparently you are doing it from another thread. We can't help you if you don't share some code.

Comment: Just because the code *worked* doesn't mean that it was right.  With threading issues, it may "work" 9999/10000 times, but that last failure will often happen in the hands of a reviewer. ;)

Comment: Also check in the stack trace that it's your code and not some third-party library.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Just call it from the main thread like this.

**Objective-C**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [[UIApplication delegate] fooBar];
});
```

**Swift**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  YourUIControlMethod()
}
```

Reaching out to your app delegate like this, is a hint that your architecture could use a little cleanup.

You can call delegates from any thread you want. You only need to make sure you're on the **main thread for UIKit** calls.
Or that you're on the correct thread your CoreData objects expect. It all depends on the API contract your objects have.

Comment: Just wondering what exactly you mean by the architecture cleanup. Say for instance I have a reference to the current context used by CoreData. I access it through my AppDelegate. Where should I put it instead?

Comment: You make separate object that wraps all your CoreData code. Then you pass that object around (dependency injection) to the view controllers that need them.

Comment: The "architecture cleanup" here refers to the fact that you should almost never reference `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` anywhere in your code. The app delegate is the *UIApplication's delegate*. It isn't a dumping ground for global storage. If you want a singleton to hold whatever you're holding here, create a new singleton. Your app delegate code should generally be fairly short, and focused only on application state transitions, not storing your model.

Comment: [But the app delegate is the closest thing to the CPU!](https://twitter.com/realbadiostips/status/866930271399981056?lang=en) (This is a joke, future reader who is unsure about iOS.)

Answer (score 25):

In Swift, you could also use `DispatchQueue.main.async` to call the UI controlling method from the main thread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    YourUIControlMethod()
}
```